# create new column by matching ID

Tags: r

I have the following example data.

```
data_1 <- data.frame("ID" = c('a','b','c','d','e'),
                 "value" = c(2,4,9,5,3))

data_2 <- data.frame("ID" = c('a','c','d','b','e','a','e','d','c'),
                     'var' =c(2,6,2,4,6,8,6,4,5))
```

I want to calculate new column in `data_2` such that for the same `ID` in the two dataset, the `value` and `var` is multiplied.

Something like for `data_1$ID==data_2$ID` then  `data_1$value*data_2$var`. So `newVar` would be `(4,54,10,16,18,16,18,20,45)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the two dataframes and multiply `value` and `var`.

```
transform(merge(data_1, data_2, by = 'ID'), result = value * var)
```

You can also use `match` :

```
transform(data_2, result = var * data_1$value[match(ID, data_1$ID)])

#  ID var result
#1  a   2      4
#2  c   6     54
#3  d   2     10
#4  b   4     16
#5  e   6     18
#6  a   8     16
#7  e   6     18
#8  d   4     20
#9  c   5     45
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(data_1, data_2, by = 'ID') %>% mutate(result = value * var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_1)[data_2, result := value * var, on = .(ID)]
```